# KDE Neon Linux (Plasma 5.19) : The screen freezes randomly

Tags: kde

I recently installed KDE-neon 5.20 and screen display freezes ramdomly.

The only workaround is to restart my system.

Spec:

- Graphics Processor: GeForce GTX 750 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
- model    : GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti]
- vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation

How to fix that?

Answer (score 4):

This solution worked well for me :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Now, reboot your system